# What's the best way to simulate a complex production web development environment?

Tags: networking, web-architecture, server-farm

I want to create a modestly scalable development environment for an in-development web service.

Ideally, there would be an nginx web server with haproxy and a few database servers, websockets, the works.

I'd be going with Amazon cloud services for all of this hosting... but I'd rather not pay for CPU cycles when I'm just developing... much less develop on a remote, cloud environment.

What's the best way to go about modeling a somewhat complex development environment locally that could - hopefully, at the press of a button - sync with a similarly architected Amazon cloud environment?

All I have is my Macbook Pro. I also have a fully built 1Ghz tower computer in the closet I could leverage, if needed, and wouldn't be opposed to buying more. But, ultimately, I'd like to have the ability to sync to production with minimal steps and reconfiguration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) and [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). That will get you local environments running nicely on your macbook. Syncing to EC2 is going to be tougher. At the system level you'll want to use something like [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://www.opscode.com/) (which are both nicely supported by vagrant). Add to that a solid automated application deployment mechanism and you should be close. Be prepared to put some time into this, it's not likely to be a trivial undertaking.